# Erratic results from RIGHT formula in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to automate jobs and I have a list of names where I both need them for emails (LastName, FirstName) or as a proper list (FirstName LastName). So I want to only type them once and generate the other version from a formula.

I'm using: `=RIGHT(B2,FIND(",",B2)-1)&" "&LEFT(B2, FIND(",",B2)-1)`

So for "Holmes, Sherlock", this should give me "Sherlock Holmes"

What I'm getting are really erratic results. I want to be able to use that even if one of the names has two parts but it plays up even with straightforward names.

Out of 22 examples, it gets 4 right.
The ones it gets right to have the same number of letters in both names. But that shouldn't matter with that method. I don't understand!

```
erlock Holmes
erry Finn
izabeth Bennett
lliam Darcy
ercule Poirot
e,Jane Marple
sday Next
n,Jane Austen
Jasper Fforde
e,Agatha Christie
,Harry Potter
ng,J.K. Rowling
eorge Eliot
ry,Antoine de Exupery
per Lee
Truman Capote
nald Dahl
George Orwell
inger,JD Salinger
Oscar Wilde
arquez,Gabriel Garcia Marquez
```

Comment: Can you post the sample input?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=RIGHT(B2, LEN(B2) - FIND(",", B2) - 1) & " " & LEFT(B2, FIND(",", B2) - 1)
```

The issue is with your logic being used in the `RIGHT` function.  You need to determine how many characters to take from the right, and to do that, you need to involve the entire length of the string.

Your current call to `LEFT` is correct, and should leave you with the substring corresponding to the last name.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I actually came with the LEN thing up myself but I didn't realise that there is a difference in how LEFT and RIGHT works so I didn't trust either! But my trial sheet has some hard test cases and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=MID(B2,SEARCH(", ",B2)+2,LEN(B2)-SEARCH(", ",B2))&" "&LEFT(B2,SEARCH(",",B2)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Slightly cleaner version, also allows for various amounts of spaces  
 and missing `,`'s  `=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(B2,SEARCH(",",B2)+1,999))&" "&TRIM(LEFT(B2,SEARCH(",",B2)-1)),B2)`

Comment: Thank you. Both of these work like a charm. And I did throw some hard ones into the mix. - I particularly like that you added Douglas Adams. :-)

Comment: @ChristineRieger - If one of these works, please mark as the Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post.  Kindly note it doesn't have to be mine, you should flag whichever answer you feel "best" solved the issue, was most clear, etc.  (And I had to add him! It was that or Zaphod :D)

Comment: I'll be honest that I'm also a big Douglas Adams fan.